# Webview capturePicture always returns null

Tags: android, android-webview

I have the following code:

```
WebView wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
Picture p = wv.capturePicture();
```

The HTML is generated and passed to the WebView. The WebView renders like expected but the variable `p` is always null. It's like it doesn't take the picture.

Can someone give me some pointers?

I tried using `loadUrl` pointing to google.com, but I still can't take a picture. I'm using Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0).

Comment: check the parameters  void loadDataWithBaseURL (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl). baseUrl the URL to use as the page's base URL. If null defaults to 'about:blank'.

Comment: I didn't knew that. But i´m loading the html. I don't have a "real" baseUrl. I tried using loadData() but with this method, the images are not loaded.

Comment: put this Picture p in onPageFinished?